# Inserting manytomany field into db

Tags: python, database, django

I'd like to insert individual squawks into the Room object so I can insert into the database. How do I do this?

I tried, Room(squawk=squawk object), but this doesn't appear to work.

```
class Squawk(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.username) + ' - ' + self.message


class Room(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    squawks = models.ManyToManyField(Squawk)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# get Room instance by id or raise 404 page if not found
room = get_object_or_404(Room,pk = id)
# add squawk to many-to-many relation
room.squawks.add(squawk_object)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/